# Adding a custom Theme to Sylius isn't working

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am trying to make a custom theme to a new project in Sylius. I have read de documentation and followed the steps to create one simple theme to start with. 
I went to channel configuration and have assigned the created theme to one of my channels but the problem is that when I load the storefront the theme isn't loading. The profiler show I am using the correct theme but it keeps loading Sylius' default layout.
Has anyone who have achieved this give me an idea if what could be missing? I'm pretty sure all of my files are in place.

Answer (score 1):

This doc pull request should help you - https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/pull/7304

Did you remember to clear the cache? ;>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me decide what to do. I was using Symfony2 template overriding method but wanted to give it a try to theming in Sylius as I think this is a cleaner method than the Symfony2's one, but I can't make it work yet for some reason.

Comment: This PR was merged some time ago. Maybe look at it [here in The Book](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/themes/themes.html) or in the [ThemeBundle docs](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusThemeBundle/index.html) :)

Comment: I just gave it another try and added a second theme definition. For my surprise, this new one worked as expected, the old one, for some reason isn't working. I used an example from the link you provided so maybe the json I was defining was wrong somehow.